# Firebird generator that increments in tenths

Tags: sequence, firebird, firebird2.5

Using Firebird 2.5, I want to create a generator that increments a column every 10 units instead of one by one. I couldn't find any reference to accomplish this in the Firebird documentation nor on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [`next value for <sequence name>`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-expressions.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-nxtvlufor) with a [sequence (generator)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-sequence.html), it can only increment by one (Firebird sequences do not have a configuration to specify a default increment of a larger value):

> Each time the `NEXT VALUE FOR seq_name` operator is used with that sequence, its value increases by 1. The `GEN_ID(seq_name, <step>)` function can be called instead, to "step" the series by a different integer number.

This also points to a workaround: use the legacy [`gen_id`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-gen_id) function with an increment larger than 1:

> Increments a generator or sequence and returns its new value. From Firebird 2.0 onward, the SQL-compliant `NEXT VALUE FOR` syntax is preferred, except when an increment other than 1 is needed.
>   [..]
>   Syntax:
>
> ```
> GEN_ID (generator-name, <step>)
> ```

In other words: use `GEN_ID(<sequence name>, 10)` to increment a sequence by 10 instead of 1.